# dc.js Weird mouse zooming for seriesChart

Tags: dc.js

I want to use the mouse zoom functionality on seriesChart and have it filter for other charts of the same group.

When I enable the zoom with `.mouseZoomable(true)` on seriesChart, and zoom the chart, the other charts become empty.

This doesn't happen when I enable it on a LineChart.

Here is a simple example: https://codepen.io/udeste/pen/ZKeXmX

(Zoom the second chart with the mouse. All is working. But when you zoom the first chart the other charts go blank.)

What am I doing wrong? Is it a `dc.seriesChart` bug?

Comment: No clue why you got a close vote on this - looks like a programming-related question. I guess it could be filed an issue but verifying bugs seems like a legitimate use of SO to me. I've checked your codepen (thanks!!) and I'm able to repro. I bet it has to do with the weird keys that the series chart requires/generates. I don't have time to troubleshoot today but hope to look into this soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `dc.seriesChart` required you to supply that strange dimension, but it didn't change the filter function accordingly.

You specified `seriesDimension` like so:

```
  var seriesDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return [+d.Expt, +d.Hours];
  });
```

But when you zoom, the `dc.coordinateGridMixin` just filters using a regular [`dc.filters.RangedFilter`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.filters.RangedFilter.html), which does not know about these kinds of two-dimensional "multikeys".

Probably since the series chart requires this kind of input, it should redefine the filter handler to also deal with multikeys. But until then, you can work around it by providing your own [`filterHandler`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filterHandler__anchor):

```
  seriesChart.filterHandler(function(dimension, filters) {
    if(filters.length === 0) // 1
      dimension.filter(null);
    else {
      console.assert(filters.length===1); // 2
      console.assert(filters[0].filterType==='RangedFilter');
      dimension.filter(function(d) { // 3
        return filters[0][0] <= d[1] && d[1] < filters[0][1];
      })
    }
  });
```

What this does:

1. Checks if this event is because the filters have been cleared, and clears the dimension's filter if so.
2. Asserts that the filter is what is expected. `coordinateGridMixin` will always supply a single `dc.filters.RangedFilter` but who knows what else could happen.
3. Supplies a substitute filter function that checks if the part of the key used by the `keyAccessor` falls within the range (instead of comparing the array with the range, which will always return false).

[Here's a working fork of your codepen.](http://codepen.io/gordonwoodhull/pen/mmWjBP?editors=0010)

(Incidentally, it looks like this examples [slams into a known issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/949) where line segments off the edge of the chart are dropped instead of clipping the segments. It won't be quite as bad if there are more points. I don't think I've found a good workaround. Hopefully we'll fix this soon.)

Comment: Hello, would you know the answer to this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696831/d3-force-directed-graph-why-dont-the-flags-appear

Comment: @Gordon Probably this issue affects also `compositeChart`

Comment: Not necessarily - it has to do with the way the series chart is usually set up with a single group using multikeys to break up the data by multiple math-dimensions. In contrast the `compositeChart` is usually set up with a crossfilter group per child chart, with ordinary keys.